# Python 2.7 import unicode_literals from __future__ gives UnicodeDecodeError while reading the file with umauts

Tags: python-2.7, file, codec, diacritics

I have a Python script which read and write a file with german umlauts (äöü) in an input file "myfile.in". I used Python version 2.7. Here a reduced version of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
if __name__=='__main__':       
    with open("myfile.in", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()  
    txt = ""        
    for line in lines: 
        txt = txt + line
    with open("myfile.out", "w") as f:
        f.write(txt)
```

This works fine.

Now I got the requirement from my customer to used the Future statement definitions and I added the following line to my Python script:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Now I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 9, in <module>
    txt = txt + line
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I resolve this problem.
Thanks for your hints Thomas

Comment: Can you upgrade to Python3? Do you know the encoding of the file you are reading?

Comment: We want to upgrade to Python 3 in the future, but in the current period not yet.

Comment: file myfile.in
myfile.in: ISO-8859 text, with no line terminators